# Fullcalendarのカルーセル遷移

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, fullcalendar

Fullcalendarを使っています。
月表示で表示されている状態からゆっくり左か右へドラッグすると次(前)のカレンダーがフェードインしてくるような描画は出来るのでしょうか？Androidの標準カレンダーのような動きができないか検討しています。

Answer (score 0):

実際に詳細なレベルで実装して確認したわけではありませんが、
fullcalendarで3か月分の画面(3画面分)を作成し、カルーセル機能で遷移させると、前月または次月へAndroidの標準カレンダのような動きが実現できるのではないかと思います。